# how to get count from two tables without subquery in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables,

```
department  
———-  
deptid (type: INT)  
deptname (type: TEXT)  
hours (type: INT)  
active (type: BIT)  

employee  
——–  
empid (type: INT)  
empname (type: TEXT)  
deptid (type: INT)  
designation (type: TEXT)  
salary (type: INT)
```

now how to make query without using subquery that returns  the columns empname and deptname of the employees belonging to those departments that have a head count of 4 or more. The records should be returned in alphabetical order of empname.

Comment: i have made solution like that:   select e.empname , d.deptname, d.`deptid`from employee e inner join department d where e.`deptid` = d.`deptid` and e.`deptid` in (select deptid from employee group by deptid having (count(`deptid`)) >= 4) order by e.empname;                    but i want it without subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an **Aggregate condition** (head count of 4 or more), that means without subquery you can not get the `empname` but only `deptname`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select E.empName, D.DeptName, count(E2.EmpID)
FROM Department D
LEFT JOIN Employee E
  ON E.DeptID = D.DeptID
LEFT JOIN Employee E2
  ON E.DeptID = D.DeptID
GROUP BY E.EmpName, D.DeptName
Having count(e2.empID) >=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this looks right to me

```
SELECT empname, deptname, department.deptid
FROM employee JOIN department ON employee.deptid = department.deptid
GROUP BY department.deptid
HAVING count(department.deptid) >= 4
ORDER BY empname;
```

Comment: If you group them by department id, then you won't see all names from each department.